# Instantiating an object within the object declaration in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

While browsing through kotlin documentation at [object expressions and declarations](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) I came across this snippet

```
class MyClass {
    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): MyClass = MyClass()
    }
}

val instance = MyClass.create()
```

In line 3, the `create` function instantiates an object `MyClass()`

In last line however, to call the `create` we already need MyClass object (don't we?).

My question is: At what point does the MyClass comes into existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invocation `val instance = MyClass.create()` is independent of *an instance* of `MyClass`, you simply use the type as a qualifier for the method (it's like `static` methods in Java). Note that you can also write `MyClass.Factory.create()`, the companion's name is redundant when calling it from Kotlin though.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. you said : "that you can also write `MyClass.Factory.create()`".. In that case, can there be more companion objects like `Factory2`, `Factory3` .. and so on?

Comment: No, only one companion is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

> In last line however, to call the create we already need MyClass object (don't we?).

No, the last line calls `.create()` on the *companion object* of `MyClass`. The companion object is an instance of a separate class (it is not `MyClass`) and is initialized before the class is first used, so you don't need an instance of `MyClass` to call `.create()`.

Note that, syntactically, `.create()` is called on the `MyClass` class name, not on an ordinary exppression like `MyClass()` constructor call or a `myClass` variable.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it is helpful.

Comment: I read your answer many times and I am not able to get following: "The companion object is an instance of a separate class (it is not MyClass) and is initialized before the class is first used" What is the separate class here. Can you please elaborate on the order of instantiation? I'm new to Kotlin.

Comment: It's very similar to calling a static method in Java.